# Issue Sending Predicted Label to API Endpoint in Flask Application

Tags: python-3.x, flask, pytorch, python-requests

Description:

I am working on a Flask application for clothing recognition, and I have encountered an issue where the predicted label is not being sent to the API endpoint as expected. I've tried various debugging steps, but I'm still facing this problem. Here's an overview of my application and the issue:

Context:

I have a Flask application that uses a trained model to predict clothing labels from images captured via a camera feed.
When a label is predicted, I want to send this label to an API endpoint using the `requests.post` method.

Code Structure:

I have a Flask route that processes the camera feed and predicts labels using the predict_and_draw_bounding_box function.
The `send_predicted_label_to_api` function is responsible for sending the predicted label to the API endpoint.

Issue:

The problem is that, while the labels are correctly predicted and logged, they are not consistently being sent to the API endpoint.

Things I've Tried:

I've checked that the `predicted_label` variable contains the correct value.
I've reviewed the conditional statements in the send_predicted_label_to_api function to ensure that the API request is sent when the conditions are met.
I've confirmed that the API endpoints (`api_url` and `api_url2`) are correct and accessible.
I've verified that the quotation_name is being retrieved correctly when calling `get_quotation_name_from_api`.

Code Samples:

Here is the relevant code for the route and functions:

```
# Function to perform inference on a single image and draw a bounding box

    def predict_and_draw_bounding_box(model, image, class_folders, frame, roi_coordinates, confidence_threshold=40):
        global predicted_label, bounding_box
    
        transform = transforms.Compose([
            transforms.Resize((224, 224)),
            transforms.ToTensor(),
        ])
        image_tensor = transform(image).unsqueeze(0)
    
        with torch.no_grad():
            outputs = model(image_tensor)
            _, predicted_class = torch.max(outputs, 1)
            class_idx = predicted_class.item()
            predicted_label = class_folders[class_idx]
    
            # Get the confidence score (based on the highest probability)
            confidence_score = torch.max(torch.softmax(outputs, 1)) * 100  # Convert to percentage
    
            # Check if the confidence score is below the threshold
            if confidence_score < confidence_threshold:
                predicted_label = "[NOTICE]-Prediction less than confidence_threshold"  # Assign "Unrecognized" label
            else:
                cv2.putText(frame, f"[INFO]-Detected Label: {predicted_label} (Confidence: {confidence_score:.2f}%)",
                            (10, 90), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 2.5, (0, 255, 0), 2)
    
        return predicted_label, confidence_score.item()
    
    
    
    
    #========================================================================================================
    #define the get quotation name from api function
    
    @app.route('/get_quotation_name', methods=['POST'])
    def get_quotation_name_from_api():
        try:
            # Get the quotation name from the request parameters
            quotation_name = request.args.get('quotation_name')
            print("Quotation Name from request:", quotation_name)
            logging.info("Quotation Name from request: %s", quotation_name)
    
            if not quotation_name:
                return jsonify({"error": "Please provide a 'quotation_name' parameter."}), 400
    
            # Make an API request to get the quotation name based on the provided name
            api_url = f'http://server:5000/{quotation_name}' # the API endpoint URL
            print("API URL:", api_url)
            logging.info("API URL: %s", api_url)
    
        except Exception as e:
            traceback.print_exc()
            error_msg = str(e)
            print("Error in get_quotation_name_from_api: %s", error_msg)
            logging.error("Error in get_quotation_name_from_api: %s", error_msg)
            return jsonify({"error": error_msg}), 500
            pass
    
        return quotation_name
    
    
    
    #========================================================================================================
    #Define the function to send label to api
    def send_predicted_label_to_api(predicted_label, api_url, api_url2, headers):
        try:
            print("Predicted label:", predicted_label)
            logging.info("Predicted label: %s", predicted_label)
    
            if predicted_label != "[NOTICE]-Prediction less than confidence_threshold":
                quotation_name = get_quotation_name_from_api()  # Make sure this function exists
                print("Quotation name:", quotation_name)
                logging.info("Quotation name: %s", quotation_name)
    
                if quotation_name != 'None':
                    data = {
                        "item_label": predicted_label,
                        "quotation": quotation_name
                    }
    
                    try:
                        response = requests.post(api_url2, headers=headers, json=data)
                        print("Request sent to API")
                        logging.info("Request sent to API")
    
                        if response.status_code == 200:
                            print("Predicted label sent to API successfully.")
                            logging.info("Predicted label sent to API successfully")
                            cv2.putText(frame, "[INFO]-Label Sent to Api: {} (Quotation: {})".format(predicted_label, quotation_name),
                                        (10, 90), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 2.5, (0, 255, 0), 2)
                        elif response.status_code == 400:
                            print("Scanned Item already exists on the server...")
                            logging.warning("Scanned Item already exists on the server")
                        else:
                            print("Unexpected status code:", response.status_code)
                            logging.warning("Unexpected status code: %s", response.status_code)
    
                    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as req_exc:
                        print("Request Exception:", str(req_exc))
                        logging.error("Request Exception: %s", str(req_exc))
                    except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as http_exc:
                        print("HTTP Error:", str(http_exc))
                        logging.error("HTTP Error: %s", str(http_exc))
    
                elif quotation_name == 'None' or not quotation_name:
                    print("Quotation name could not be retrieved from the API, will attempt to create a new item under no quotation..")
                    logging.info("Quotation name could not be retrieved from the API, attempting to create a new item under no quotation")
                    data = {
                        "label": predicted_label
                    }
    
                    try:
                        response = requests.post(api_url, headers=headers, json=data)
                        print("Request sent to API")
                        logging.info("Request sent to API")
    
                        if response.status_code == 200:
                            print("Predicted label sent to API successfully.")
                            logging.info("Predicted label sent to API successfully")
                        elif response.status_code == 400:
                            print("Scanned Item already exists on the server...")
                            logging.warning("Scanned Item already exists on the server")
                        else:
                            print("Unexpected status code:", response.status_code)
                            logging.warning("Unexpected status code: %s", response.status_code)
    
                    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as req_exc:
                        print("Request Exception:", str(req_exc))
                        logging.error("Request Exception: %s", str(req_exc))
                    except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as http_exc:
                        print("HTTP Error:", str(http_exc))
                        logging.error("HTTP Error: %s", str(http_exc))
                else:
                    print("Unexpected error:", response.status_code)
                    logging.warning("Unexpected error: %s", response.status_code)
    
            else:
                print("Label is unrecognized and won't be sent to the API.")
                logging.info("Label is unrecognized and won't be sent to the API")
    
        except Exception as e:
            error_msg = str(e)
            print("General Exception: %s" % error_msg)
            logging.error("General Exception: %s", error_msg)
    
    
    #========================================================================================================
    
    # Function to perform inference on a single image
    def predict_clothes(model, image, class_folders):
        transform = transforms.Compose([
            transforms.Resize((224, 224)),
            transforms.ToTensor(),
        ])
        image_tensor = transform(image).unsqueeze(0)
    
        with torch.no_grad():
            outputs = model(image_tensor)
            _, predicted_class = torch.max(outputs, 1)
            class_idx = predicted_class.item()
            predicted_label = class_folders[class_idx]
    
            # Get the confidence score (based on the highest probability)
            confidence_score = torch.max(torch.softmax(outputs, 1)) * 100  # Convert to percentage
    
        return predicted_label, confidence_score.item()
    
    
    
    #========================================================================================================
    
    # Define a function to generate frames for the video stream
    
    def generate_frames():
        model_path = "clothes_recognizer_modelcp.pt"
        data_dir = "path"
        class_folders = sorted(os.listdir(data_dir))
        num_classes = len(class_folders)
        trained_model = load_trained_model(model_path, num_classes)
        url = "/dev/video0"
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(url)
        previous_label = None
        last_detection_time = 0
        countdown_duration = 5
        counting_down = False
        display_detected_label = False
        display_detected_label_start_time = 0
        display_detected_label_duration = 5
        detected_label = None
    
        while cap.isOpened():
            ret, frame = cap.read()
            if not ret:
                break
    
            window_width = 2900
            window_height =1800
            frame = cv2.resize(frame, (window_width, window_height))
            image = Image.fromarray(cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
            image_np = np.array(image)
    
            current_time = time.time()
            time_since_last_detection = current_time - last_detection_time
    
            if not counting_down:
                if bounding_box is not None:
                    x1, y1, x2, y2 = bounding_box
                    frame = frame[y1:y2, x1:x2]
    
                if display_detected_label:
                    cv2.putText(frame, f"Label: {detected_label} (Conf: {predicted_confidence:.2f}%)", (10, 90), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX, 2, (0, 255, 0), 2)
                    if current_time - display_detected_label_start_time >= display_detected_label_duration:
                        display_detected_label = False
                else:
                    start_time = time.time()
                    detected_label, predicted_confidence = predict_and_draw_bounding_box(trained_model, image, class_folders, frame, bounding_box)
                    end_time = time.time()
                    elapsed_time = end_time - start_time
    
                    cv2.putText(frame, "Detecting...", (10, 60), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 2.5, (0, 255, 0), 2)
    
                    if detected_label:
                        confidence_note = ""
                        if detected_label == "[NOTICE]-Prediction less than confidence_threshold":
                            confidence_note = " (Program not confident)"
                            detected_label = "Label:" + predicted_label # Reset detected label
                        label_confidence = f"{detected_label} {predicted_confidence:.2f}%{confidence_note}"
                        log_message = label_confidence
                        print(label_confidence)
                        logger.info(log_message)  # Log the message
    
                        if not display_detected_label:
                            display_detected_label = True
                            display_detected_label_start_time = current_time
                    else:
                        text_color = (0, 0, 255)
                        log_message = "Item not recognized!"
                        print(log_message)
                        logger.info(log_message)  # Log the message
    
                    if detected_label:
                        if detected_label != previous_label:
                            send_predicted_label_to_api(detected_label, api_url, api_url2, headers)
                            previous_label = detected_label
                        last_detection_time = current_time
    
                if not display_detected_label and time_since_last_detection >= display_detected_label_duration:
                    counting_down = True
                    countdown_start_time = current_time
                    countdown_end_time = current_time + countdown_duration
    
            else:
                remaining_time = countdown_end_time - current_time
    
                if remaining_time > 0:
                    cv2.putText(frame, f"Countdown: {int(remaining_time)} seconds", (10, 30), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX, 2, (255, 0, 0), 2)
                    cv2.putText(frame, "next detection after countdown...", (10, 60), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX, 1, (0, 0, 255), 2)
                else:
                    counting_down = False
    
            if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                break
    
            _, buffer = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)
            frame_bytes = buffer.tobytes()
            yield (b'--frame\r\n'
                   b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame_bytes + b'\r\n')
        else:
            error_msg = "Camera could not be established, check the connection.."
            print(error_msg)
            logger.error(error_msg)  # Log the error message
    
        cap.release()
    
    #========================================================================================================    
    # Define a route for the video stream
    
    @app.route('/video_feed')
    def video_feed():
        return Response(generate_frames(), mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')
    
    
    #========================================================================================================
    # Define a route to render the HTML page
    
    @app.route('/')
    def index():
        return render_template('index.html')
```

Expected Outcome:

I expect that when the conditions are met (e.g., confidence threshold is exceeded), the predicted label should be sent to the API endpoint.

Question:

What could be causing the label not to be sent to the API endpoint despite the code appearing to work correctly?
Are there common pitfalls or issues to watch out for when making API requests within a Flask application?
How can I further troubleshoot this issue and ensure that the label is consistently sent to the API endpoint?

I appreciate any guidance or insights to help resolve this issue.

Comment: -I have included more prints and error handling exceptions to the code , and when I ran it I got RuntimeError: Working outside of request context."
-Following the this blog[https://testdriven.io/blog/flask-contexts/] investigating more on flask context. discovered that flask relies on something called request context to handle http requests which allows us access to specific functionalities.
-The error occured because I used request.args outside of a flask route,so I made separate function to retrieve the quotation from the sending and made sure to call it within the flask route.

Comment: However I am always getting a 500 response code:
Quotation name not found in the API response.
Quotation name could not be retrieved from the API, will attempt to create a new item under no quotation..
Request sent to API
Unexpected status code: 500